# RestSharp specifying the default JsonSerializer in version 107

Tags: restsharp

In the current code which is using older version of RestSharp there is option to specify the default JsonSerializer, I am not able to figure out how to do specify request.JsonSerializer in version 107

```
            var request = new RestRequest("abc");
            request.AddHeader(Constants.HttpHeaderNames.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");            
            request.JsonSerializer = NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Default;
```

Answer (score 6):

Request-specific serializers are no longer supported. The proper way of using RestSharp (similar to `HttpClient`) is to have one instance per API client instance. Normally, an API you talk to has the same serialization for all its endpoints.

If you must use `NewtonsoftJson`, use it as [described](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#newtonsoftjson-aka-json-net) in the docs.

```
client.UseNewtonsoftJson();
```

And please, don't add the content type header.

As the API might change, you can always reference to the latest version [docs](https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html).

**UPDATE 26 April 2023**

The current latest v110 has the serialiser configuration moved to `RestSharpOptions`. It was done to avoid changing the serialiser during concurrent calls, which might create weird side effects.

The new API can be used like this:

```
var client = new RestClient(
    options, 
    configureSerialization: s => s.UseSerializer(() => new CustomSerializer());
);
```

There is a discussion to add an option to have a serialiser set per request.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an option in 110.2.0.  Has the interface changed?

Comment: It's in the docs. I am updating the answer.